# Changing the elements of an array through methods?

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods

So I have

```
myArray2 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
```

How will I change myArray2 to:

```
copyOfArray = ["a", "c", "d", "e"]
```

without

```
copyOfArray[1] = "c";
copyOfArray[2] = 'd';
copyOfArray[3] = 'e';
```

I'm supposed to use methods to change the values of myArray2 to copyOfArray in JavaScript.

Comment: Lots of ways to do this.  One way would be to slice the original array to get a copy, then splice out the second element, and push the `e` on the end

Comment: This sounds a little like homework, in which case you should really check with your instructor about this. But arrays have lots of methods. See the documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array. Some of those may do what you need.

Comment: I saw @Taplar's comment I get it now, thanks and btw I'm totally new to JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1)** This can be an approach using the `splice()` function to remove the "b" element and `push` the "e" element at the end:

```js
var myArray2 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];

myArray2.splice(1, 1);
myArray2.push("e");

console.log(myArray2);
```

**2)** As @Kinglish said, it can be achieved using two `splice()` functions, one to remove the "b" element and the other to add the "e" element:

```js
var myArray2 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];

myArray2.splice(1, 1);
myArray2.splice(3, 0, "e");

console.log(myArray2);
```

Comment: sry, didn't realize it wasn't a replace in the same position... nevermind

Comment: Yes, but also it´s good to know that splice can be used as push when you know the length of the array

Answer (score 0):

```js
const myArray = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];

// create a copy of myArray
const copyOfArray = [...myArray];

// removes 'b' from copyOfArray
copyOfArray.splice(1,1);

// add 'e' in the end of copyOfArray
copyOfArray.push("e")

console.log(copyOfArray,myArray)
// [ 'a', 'c', 'd', 'e' ] [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' ]
```

You can use .splice to remove the item you want of the array, and .push to add in the end of it

```
const myArray = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];

// create a copy of myArray
const copyOfArray = [...myArray];

// removes 'b' from copyOfArray
copyOfArray.splice(1,1);

// add 'e' in the end of copyOfArray
copyOfArray.push("e")

console.log(copyOfArray,myArray)
// [ 'a', 'c', 'd', 'e' ] [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' ]
```